# How to reload ng-repeat after removing item

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a question about ng-repeat.
I have this webpage where I upload pictures getting them from a json response, and I added a plugin (flex-images), which handles the pictures size and look.
The fact is : the plugin works only if the picture array gets refreshed, but it does not happen when I remove items from the picture array.
My question is : how can I force ng-repeat to refresh?
The code is below, thanks in advance:

```
app.directive('onLastRepeat', function() {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {

    if (scope.$last) setTimeout(function() {
        $('#items').flexImages({ rowHeight: 500 });
    }, 1);
};
```

});

```
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope,       $window, $location, $timeout, ngDialog, toaster, $sce) {


 $scope.deletePicture = function(id,index) {
    $scope.pictures.splice(index, 1);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to reload anything. Angular will observe the changes on the object passed to `ng-repeat` and automatically re-renders the view by computing `$digest` on the scope.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to refresh your view. Just remove the data from your  `$scope.pictures` using `splice` method the way you did and then push the updated data into `$scope.pictures` like:

```
$scope.pictures.push(updated_data);
```